# Is there any way to detect app sandbox environment/parameters on myself's development Mac?

Tags: macos, cocoa

My code below works well on my MAC, but after submitted the app for Apple review, they said there are some conflicts with app sandbox rules.

```
OSStatus error = noErr;
error = SendAppleEventToSystemProcess(kAESleep);
if(error!=noErr){

    NSLog (@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)error]);
    return;
}
```

I used the code above try to catch the error when it occurs.

but on my Mac, it always works well without any problem/error.

Just wonder if there is any way to detect app sandbox environment/parameters on myself's development Mac?

Comment: Every sandboxed app from app store has Receipt or use NSDictionary *environment = [NSProcessInfo processInfo].environment;
        NSString *sanboxID = environment[@"APP_SANDBOX_CONTAINER_ID"];

Comment: Also try to make another user on your Mac and try to run your app in that account. Faster might be tccutil reset https://www.macblog.org/post/reset-tcc-privacy/